# Dictionary inside dictionary from AJAX to Django

Tags: json, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-1.8

My javascript code is like this:

```
var emotions = {};


$('#emotions').children('#emotionFields').each(function(){
        emotions[$(this).find($('.emotion')).val()]=$(this).find($('.value')).val()
    });

$.ajax({
            url: '../data',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {action: 'dosomething',word:word,emotions:emotions},
            success:function(response){
            //something  
            },
            error:function(msg){
                   //somethin
            }
});
```

So just before the ajax call my emotions object looks like this:

```
emotions: Object
excitement: "value1"
guilt: "value2"
```

When I read this data from djangos request.GET I see

```
{u'action': u'dosomething',
 u'emotions[excitement]': u'value1',
 u'emotions[guilt]': u'value2',
 u'word': u'word'}
```

Now, How do I convert this to a proper dictionary where I can access the excitement and guilt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before sending your data try doing a `JSON.stringify()`.

```
...
$.ajax({
    ...
    contentType : "application/json",
    data : JSON.stringify({action: 'dosomething',word:word,emotions:emotions}),
    ...
...
```

And then in your Django view:

```
...
data = json.loads(request.body)
print data['emotions']['guilt']
...
```

If the above code does not satisfy your requirement then you can use this [library](https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser).

**EDIT:** If Django version is <1.6 then use `request.raw_post_data` instead of `request.body`.

Comment: This works partially because I do get data in that form but at the backend I have to do json.loads(request.GET.keys()[0]) to get that data, this looks like a bad hack to me :D, is there a better way of doing it ?

Comment: @dnit13 - Try doing a `data = json.loads(request.body)` and then try `data['emotions']['guilt']`

Comment: @dnit13 - If that does not satisfy your requirement then I guess this [library](https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser) will be helpful for you.